# Factorising $x^7-7x^6+21x^5-35x^4+35x^3-21x^2+20x+14$ into $\Bbb Q$-irreducible factors (Eisenstein's Criterion)

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Factorize $x^7-7x^6+21x^5-35x^4+35x^3-21x^2+20x+14$ into $\Bbb Q$-irreducible factors.

I've made the substitution $y=x-1$.

So I get $y^7+13y+28$ which satisfies Eisenstein's Criterion for $p=13$. Does this mean that the original polynomial can not be factorised further?

Comment: You mean $26$ as a constant term?

Comment: If $26$ it is, then irreducible the transformed polynomial is, and if the original had been reducible, then the transformation applied to its factors would factorize the transformed one, which we know is impossible.

Comment: OK, I did the calculation, and it's actually $28$, so Eisenstein does not apply here.

Comment: Could you explain why Eisenstein does not apply please? As I understand it the constant term can't equal zero mod $p^2$, isn't this true for 28 mod 169? @AndreasCaranti

Comment: @TheProblem What is $13\cdot 2$?

Comment: To apply Eisenstein, you need $p$ (but not $p^2$) to divide the constant term.

Comment: 26, could you please explain whatever point you're trying to make @GitGud

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the clarification @AndreasCaranti

Comment: @TheProblem My point is that $13$ does not divide $28$.

Comment: So since we can not apply Eisenstien does this imply it can be factorised further?

Comment: @TheProblem The answer is no. And we still don't know that we can't use Eisenstein's criterion, maybe we just have found the right substitution yet.

Comment: It might (or might not) help to compare your polynomial to $(x-1)^7$.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did to get the equation in y @GerryMyerson

Comment: Well, if that doesn't get you anywhere, then I suggest 1) the problem is much too hard to do without a computer algebra program to do it for you, or 2) there's a typo in the problem.

Comment: BTW, I have checked with a CAS, and the polynomial appears indeed to be irreducible. But unless (as suggested by Gerry Myerson) that 20 is really a 21, I have no idea how to prove it with Eisenstein. (Reduction modulo various primes may be a way.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I guess maybe it is a typo. @AndreasCaranti